# AS3 Display Objects & Sprites (Adding children based on a random number)

Tags: object, children, sprite, displaylist

ActionScript 3.0

Essentially I need a function that displays a random number of butterfly objects. (Also I should make a reset function that resets the first function.)

I find though that the butterflies are not even displayed to begin with, It seems that the children are not being added to the stage even though I used the addChild().

Any help is appreciate thanks!

// Random Number

```
        var randomNumber : int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);

// New Sprite

        var bContainer: Sprite = new Sprite();
        this.addChild(bContainer);

        var butterfly: MovieClip = new Butterfly();
        bContainer.addChild(butterfly);

//Function to Create Butterfly Objects:

        function showButterfly(randomNumber:int):void {

            while(bContainer.numChildren < randomNumber){
                bContainer.addChild(butterfly);
            }

//Reset Function, I am not sure about this (especially the second one)

        function button(evt:MouseEvent): void {

                if(numChildren>0) {
                   removeChildAt(0);
                }

                if(numChildren==0) {
                    showButterfly();
                }
        }

// Event Listener

        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN);
//
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but aren't you suppose to set the width and height for the sprite that works as a holder object?

```
var bContainer: Sprite = new Sprite();
bContainer.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
bContainer.graphics.drawRect(0, 0,stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
addChildAt(bContainer, 0);
```